# Typo3 assign BE-Group on new created pages not working as it should

Tags: typo3, rights-management

on my Typo3 page i have set up a rights managment, all is working well until one point. I will first explain a little bit of my setup.

Every page (+ its subpages) got a group assigned that is assigned to a sitegroup-group, which is assigned to a meta group that can be assigned to the BE-users. When a BE-User is creating a new page in his "area" the metagroup is assigned to the page, but i need to assign a special group for each page (again including its subpages, they got the same).

I tried several ways like adding this:

```
TCEMAIN {
    permissions.userid = 1
    permissions.groupid = 20
}
```

to the TypoScript of the page that will contain the subpages it have be automatically assign to the group with the id 20.

Please guys just throw in your thoughts every answer is much appreciated.

And i have to say, that I´am very sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add it to the "Page TSConfig" section.